# Do undefined concepts or assumptions have to exist?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-language

In philosophy, we have the notion that definitions are infinitely regressive if we take the attitude of trying to define everything and it is unending. But of course, the very idea of an “infinite regress” is itself never defined and yet seems to be the constant of this never ending … thing or process or what have you.

But, it seems that this is counter to what we wish to do. How do we define things using things which are already defined? And yet even this framework is just that… a framework. It is something we intuitively know and yet even this idea of “intuitively know” is another framework. It does not have an explanation but we know what it means.

I do not wish to go the Buddhist route and say philosophy and logic is in a sense always like this and possibly even pointless. But I would also like to see some serious counters to this. Even everything I’m writing now is within a certain net of understandings.

Some say “meaning” is isomorphism. Or, rather, I should say whatever your explanation for things are, that theory in itself is just another thing. Even the idea of needing an explanation is a thing, for clearly it is different from an apple. We use words to try and define words or our usage of them in philosophy and it all seems circular.

Can this be remedied?

Edit 1: it seems that my question was a bit misleading. Also possibly futile. I am asking essentially a pointless question in a sense or maybe not, but how can we use words to define words? Does not everything we say assume something and these assumptions have certain… let’s say forms. For instance, the sentence, “ definitions are infinitely regressive”. This sentence, although intuitive, is very dense and comes with a heck of a lot of assumptions and frameworks and maybe these are all created from basic marks or signs of you take the analytic approach or they are merely subdivisions of a holy object if you take the top to bottom approach or whatever else have you.

It seems philosophy lacks a basis or a contingency even. Why this framework of “infinitely regressive”? And what if it’s definition? I am reminded constantly in these moments to be wary of mysticism. The Buddhists may say it is dependent origination, but then again even this is just an idea. It has an implicit definition as such. But, yet in meaning (or to borrow a model theoretic term) it’s model or implementation it somehow also applies to itself and becomes a weird possibly nondual but not Hegelian monster. And yet I can still negate even this framework from other ideas like the idea of a framework unlike it and still end up with the same question.

Maybe I am having difficulties with marks vs. meaning or semantics or “use” to cite Wittgensteins approach given below.

Comment: No if one rejects the [foundationalist model of justification](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/justep-foundational/), and gives up on defining and justifying in a hierarchical linguistic manner. The "ultimate" ground of conception and justification can then be placed beyond propositional content, beyond the "sea of words" and conceptual frameworks, in actions and practices, for example, see [pragmatist epistemology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pragmatism/#PragEpis). But anti-foundationalism has its costs, see e.g. [meaning holism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/meaning-holism/).

Comment: @Conifold I have to say. Although I agree with this, that there is a caveat. Which may be considered extreme or even just plain dumb. Here goes nothing: the response you wrote itself with its full “network” worked out or even not worked out. Is it not still assuming itself? Even the idea of assumptions and of “and of’s…” is … something, no? I realize it may be odd trying to do this using words themselves but the question is still lingering.

Comment: Generally speaking, no. Thinking or saying something does not require assuming it, and even acting on it does not. Not even assuming the conceptual framework normally used to make sense of the words is required, allusions and metaphors are not there for nothing.

Comment: Obviously every argument/theory needs assumptions (statements without proof) with which to start the inferential process as well as undefined terms from which new concepts can be defined.

Comment: @Conifold I like this answer, but I can’t help but feel that it is still something taken for granted. Axiomatic almost. You are simply saying that it requires no assumption for me to think something, but yet even the idea of “thinking something” is a system on its own, almost premade and already there. Although I guess this framework of mine assumes also the existence of a state of no assumptions or no thing to contrast from: which is also just yet another idea. So it ends up circular and somehow also … not circular too? Very odd

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA I agree with this in a sense too. It seems that definitions are only possible using the negations of a thing. For instance, to say a dog is a dog is not really informative, but to borrow a medieval term, it does have a haeccity or essence or what have you that we just intuitively know. But, then again, I believe it was … Russell ? That completely demolished the theory of haeccities and to an extent Whitehead? I’d love to chat with you about this more.

Comment: Something is taken for granted, but it isn't assumptions. It is skills to act and think, which are prior to any ideas of acting and thinking. They are "already there", or rather developed practically, but they are not a system or capable of "assuming" anything. Only to their conceptual descriptions your circularity argument can be applied, but they are quite distinct from those descriptions and so there is no circularity. It is only our tendency to identify descriptions with what they describe that creates the impression.

Answer (score 0):

Wittgenstein's approach to this problem is to suggest that the meaning of a word is intrinsically related (or perhaps 'extrinsically related' would work better here) to the social use of the object being referred to. A particular object is called a 'brick' because objects of that type are extremely useful for any number of purposes, and we periodically want to ask others to find, make, store, carry, and/or use such objects. Thus we give the word 'brick' the loose definition of 'a thing we are likely to use in *that* particular context and way'. It isn't precisely circular reasoning or or an infinite regress. Instead, it puts the foundation of language-meaning in something that isn't linguistic at all — a habit, custom, practice, etc. — so that when one tries to talk about it, one starts to sound like an idiot.

Of course, this gets us to a metaphysical question: since all specific objects that we refer to as 'bricks' are unique and individual, what precisely are we referring to when we use 'brick' in the abstract? This is the kind of question that led Plato to the theory of ideal forms: asserting that there was some idealized *form* of a brick that we refer to, and that every *actual* brick is an imperfect but recognizable manifestation of that form. It's also what led Russell to take such a keen interest in the logic and mathematics of set theory, because understanding how things are grouped together is key to understanding how a single signifier can point at multiple interchangeable referents. Wittgenstein himself ultimately rested meaning in two principles:

- Conventional standards: We all agree (explicitly or implicitly) that *such* is the definition of a word. His concrete example is the meter-rod in Paris, which (for a time) was the standard for defining a length of one meter. We knew that anything else was one meter long by comparing it (directly or indirectly) to that rod, but the rod itself is only one meter *by convention*: it is one meter long merely because somebody asserted it was, and everyone else went along with it.
- Family resemblances: we tend to group things by loose pairwise comparisons more than analytical analysis. Bricks have a number of useful attributes and properties — strength, hardness, regularity of shape, opacity, etc. and two objects might be called 'bricks' because they are similar enough on one or a few of those properties to be used in the way we conventionally use bricks. Thus objects of different shapes, sizes, and materials might all be called bricks, because they are used like bricks in their respective contexts, but even though 'tiles' are quite similar to bricks in some dimensions (e.g., regularity of shape and hardness) they are used in a different way, and thus merit a different word.

The upshot is that if we try to define meaning strictly within language, we will always end up at the moral equivalent of one of Zeno's paradoxes, proving to ourselves that we can never reach our goal of a 'definition' because there is endless string of recursive intermediary steps we must take before we can get there. Instead, language is a more ramshackle process: we assert terms as though they are universally defined as we think they are, and deal with the problems that arise if and when someone has a different view. Try to make it too exact (to use the daoist metaphor) and we just end up breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is answersble. yet, i have to say i detect a note of global skepticism here.

it should be tantamount to remember first that we cannot doubt reasoning or logic itself. otherwise, what we would end up with isnt even chaos, since chaos fits into an actually very orderly concept of duality. chaos-order etc. Actually anything which has an identity and a distinction is already considered a beast of reason and what can be conceived itself is a type of compositional reason. you cannot actualy envision something truly that ... well idk what to even call it.

although, i suppose you could attack even that logical reasoning itself.

but id point out that you yourself are drawing conclusions, and making implications which is apart of reasoning

specificaly, what concepts are you doubting? the concept of "infinite regress" doesnt seem to be being doubted by you and clearly the concept of doubt itself is not.

the "framework" as you say of things and definitions and of things having definitions doesnt seem to be doubted.

also obviously you believe in the semantic meaning of your words.

you actually are using a lot of assumptions yourself in being able to even formulate the question.

so without anything, id say is still a framework as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).